# Google Colab using XGBoost with "gpu_hist" suddenly slower

Tags: gpu, google-colaboratory, xgboost

I have been running some XGBoost regressions on Google Colab on a training set with 3mm data points and about 40 features. Today the runtime for each regression has gone from about 4s to 240s. Using `tree_method="hist"` is now faster than `gpu_hist`. Has anyone else experienced this please?

I have installed the linux GPU version and specified `tree_method="gpu_hist"`.
I have set and reset the runtime type to GPU multiple times without any success.
GPU memory does not seem to be a problem either:

```
`[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 10791916159412462458
, name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_CPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8329653355733370145
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 8283103013471747914
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
, name: "/device:GPU:0"
device_type: "GPU"
memory_limit: 11123789005
locality {
  bus_id: 1
  links {
  }
}
incarnation: 2057146031472419157
physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:00:04.0, compute capability: 3.7"
]`
```